# How to count entries of the same value for each individual row of a data frame?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, count, automation

Let's assume I have a large data frame that consists of an order date, a user ID and an item ID.

```
   order_id order_date user_id item_id
1         1 2016-06-22   30822     643
2         2 2016-06-22   30822     337
3         3 2016-06-22   30823     270
4         4 2016-06-22   30823     142
5         5 2016-06-22   30823     561
6         6 2016-06-22   30823     561
7         7 2016-06-22   30823      72
8         8 2016-06-22   30823     106
9         9 2016-06-22   30823     195
10       10 2016-06-22   30823     195
```

What I want to do is count how many orders have been placed on the same day by the same user and how many orders of the same item have been placed by the same user and display both values in a fourth and fifth column. So the result should look something like this:

```
   order_id order_date user_id item_id same_day same_item
1         1 2016-06-22   30822     643        2         1
2         2 2016-06-22   30822     337        2         1
3         3 2016-06-22   30823     270        8         1
4         4 2016-06-22   30823     142        8         1
5         5 2016-06-22   30823     561        8         2
6         6 2016-06-22   30823     561        8         2
7         7 2016-06-22   30823      72        8         1
8         8 2016-06-22   30823     106        8         1
9         9 2016-06-22   30823     195        8         2
10       10 2016-06-22   30823     195        8         2
```

Alternatively a binary variable displaying whether the item has been ordered more than once would do the job too. I know that this can be easily calculated for each row using `sum()`:

```
> sum(df$order_date=="2016-06-22" & df$user_id==30823)
[1] 8
> sum(df$item_id==561 & df$user_id==30823)
[1] 2
```

But I'd rather have it run automatically then to have to do it by hand for thousands of entries. I'm seriously running out of ideas and would be *very* thankful for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, same_day := .N, by = .(order_date, user_id)]
df[, same_item := .N, by = .(order_date, user_id, item_id)]

df
#     order_id order_date user_id item_id same_day same_item
#  1:        1 2016-06-22   30822     643        2         1
#  2:        2 2016-06-22   30822     337        2         1
#  3:        3 2016-06-22   30823     270        8         1
#  4:        4 2016-06-22   30823     142        8         1
#  5:        5 2016-06-22   30823     561        8         2
#  6:        6 2016-06-22   30823     561        8         2
#  7:        7 2016-06-22   30823      72        8         1
#  8:        8 2016-06-22   30823     106        8         1
#  9:        9 2016-06-22   30823     195        8         2
# 10:       10 2016-06-22   30823     195        8         2
```

Or with dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

df <- 
 df %>% 
   add_count(order_date, user_id, name = 'same_day') %>% 
   add_count(order_date, user_id, item_id, name = 'same_item')

df
# # A tibble: 10 x 6
#    order_id order_date user_id item_id same_day same_item
#       <int> <chr>        <int>   <int>    <int>     <int>
#  1        1 2016-06-22   30822     643        2         1
#  2        2 2016-06-22   30822     337        2         1
#  3        3 2016-06-22   30823     270        8         1
#  4        4 2016-06-22   30823     142        8         1
#  5        5 2016-06-22   30823     561        8         2
#  6        6 2016-06-22   30823     561        8         2
#  7        7 2016-06-22   30823      72        8         1
#  8        8 2016-06-22   30823     106        8         1
#  9        9 2016-06-22   30823     195        8         2
# 10       10 2016-06-22   30823     195        8         2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I could make the first approach work, even on the very large dataset, without any issues. The dplyr approach seems to not alter the data frame itself, but only output the solution. This worked fine, but was not what I intended to do.

Comment: Yeah data.table is very efficient with grouping. For the `dplyr` solution, you would have to reassign to `df` (by adding `df <-` in the line above `df %>%`), but I think that should be slower/more memory intensive than the data.table method.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a base R solution using `ave`

```
df$same_day <- with(df,ave(item_id,order_date,user_id,FUN = length))
df$same_item <- with(df,ave(item_id,order_date,user_id,item_id,FUN = length))
```

such that

```
> df
   order_id order_date user_id item_id same_day same_item
1         1 2016-06-22   30822     643        2         1
2         2 2016-06-22   30822     337        2         1
3         3 2016-06-22   30823     270        8         1
4         4 2016-06-22   30823     142        8         1
5         5 2016-06-22   30823     561        8         2
6         6 2016-06-22   30823     561        8         2
7         7 2016-06-22   30823      72        8         1
8         8 2016-06-22   30823     106        8         1
9         9 2016-06-22   30823     195        8         2
10       10 2016-06-22   30823     195        8         2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This is an easy solution that worked! Unfortunately it seems to have been too memory intensive for the size of my data frame (or for my PC, anyway R crashed after applying it to the entire dataset).

Comment: @Zwiebak well, maybe that is one of the limitations of using base R...

Comment: @Zwiebak You can still find base r solutions for it. dplyr is mostly written in R + some C

Answer (score 5):

Two `dplyr` approaches.

The first is to create groups and add variables that have the number of corresponding observations:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  mutate(same_day = length(order_date)) %>%
  group_by(user_id, item_id) %>%
  mutate(same_item = length(item_id))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 6
#> # Groups:   user_id, item_id [8]
#>    order_id order_date user_id item_id same_day same_item
#>       <int> <fct>        <int>   <int>    <int>     <int>
#>  1        1 2016-06-22   30822     643        2         1
#>  2        2 2016-06-22   30822     337        2         1
#>  3        3 2016-06-22   30823     270        8         1
#>  4        4 2016-06-22   30823     142        8         1
#>  5        5 2016-06-22   30823     561        8         2
#>  6        6 2016-06-22   30823     561        8         2
#>  7        7 2016-06-22   30823      72        8         1
#>  8        8 2016-06-22   30823     106        8         1
#>  9        9 2016-06-22   30823     195        8         2
#> 10       10 2016-06-22   30823     195        8         2
```

The second is to create two summary tables, one for each of `same_day` and `same_item`. The summary tables only have as many rows as summary values and are then repeated through the left-joins. This works like SQL subqueries, if that's familiar for you.

```r
df %>%
  left_join(
    df %>%
      count(user_id, name = "same_day"),
    by = "user_id"
  ) %>%
  left_join(
    df %>%
      count(user_id, item_id, name = "same_item"),
    by = c("user_id", "item_id")
  )
# same output
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Unfortunately I was not able to make any of your approaches work. Both times I received an error message, that 'dat' was not found, even though I previously loaded dplyr... have I forgotten something?

Comment: `dat` in this answer is just a placeholder for the name of your data. You can replace it with `df` if that's what your data is named.

Comment: Yeah I just didn't notice what you'd called the data frame and gave it a different default name. I'll edit to match

Answer (score 1):

#### You can use the dplyr package

You can use `dplyr` to achieve the desidered result:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>%
  group_by(order_date, user_id) %>% mutate(same_day = n()) %>%
  group_by(item_id, user_id) %>% mutate(same_item = n()) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 6
   order_id order_date user_id item_id same_day same_item
      <int> <fct>        <int>   <int>    <int>     <int>
 1        1 2016-06-22   30822     643        2         1
 2        2 2016-06-22   30822     337        2         1
 3        3 2016-06-22   30823     270        8         1
 4        4 2016-06-22   30823     142        8         1
 5        5 2016-06-22   30823     561        8         2
 6        6 2016-06-22   30823     561        8         2
 7        7 2016-06-22   30823      72        8         1
 8        8 2016-06-22   30823     106        8         1
 9        9 2016-06-22   30823     195        8         2
10       10 2016-06-22   30823     195        8         2
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help!